# pandas DataFrame plot marker

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Is there a way to set the marker style in pandas.DataFrame.plot? All other options are available by setting the kind. I would like a marker with error bar but just get a line with an error bar. If I was to do this through the function errorbar I would set fmt='.'

Comment: Sorry I posted an answer and then deleted it but was `df.plot(style='.')` what you were after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`df.plot` passes extra keyword parameters along to the underlying matplotlib plotting function. Thus,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.arange(10), 'y':np.random.randn(10), 
                   'err':np.random.randn(10)})
df.plot('x', 'y', yerr='err', fmt='.')
```

yields

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The OP does not specify it, but it depends whether you're trying to plot the Dataframe, or a series.

## Plotting DataFrame

Reusing the example by @unutbu:

```
from numpy import arange, random
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': arange(10), 'y': random.randn(10), 'err': random.randn(10)})
df.plot('x', 'y', yerr='err', fmt='.')
```

## Plotting Series in DataFrame

This time it's a bit different:

```
df.y.plot(fmt='.')
AttributeError: Unknown property fmt
```

you need:

```
df.y.plot(style='.')
```

[image: Plot of series]

## DataFrame behavior with `style`

If you pass `style` to `DataFrame.plot`, "nothing happens":

```
df.plot('x', 'y', yerr='err', style='.')
```

[image: Dataframe plot with default fmt]

which may be not what you want.